# Cubic B-spline curve in Java

Tags: java, graphics

I need to use a cubic B-spline curve but cannot find code for it anywhere. The only curves available in Java API are `QuadCurve2D`, `Path2D` and `CubicCurve2D`. I think they all are Bezier, but I'm not sure about it.

If you know where can I find code for cubic B-spline preferably that extends Java `Shape` class and supports `contains(Point p)` for `onMouseOver` please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache has a class to represent spline curves:

http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/visualizers/Spline3.html

However, it doesn't extend Shape or support what you want.  The class works by interpolating the curve between nodes with a cubic curve.  For contains(Point P) You might be able to use the getPlots() method, compare its results to the x and y values of P.

Answer (score 3):

CubicCurve2D is a cubic B-spline.

However, this may or may not be what you need as there are other cubic B-splines.

That is, all CubicCurve2Ds are cubic B-splines. Not all cubic B-splines are CubicCurve2Ds.

Comment: Yeah, I have realised this is the same after comparing the CubicCurve2D with a cubic B-spline I found in one of the applets on the web. Thanks though :)